# How to get the window handle of another app minimized to the system tray?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, system-tray

Instance A is trying to restore instance B's window, but I can't get the B's window handle. I think the problem is that the window is being minimized by B to the system tray using:

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

And A is trying to get B's window handle using:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Process.GetProcessesByName(process.ProcessName).First().MainWindowHandle;
```

Which is equal to `IntPtr.Zero`.

I also tried to get the window handle by class name using Spy++ but the class name has a per-instance GUID in the following format:

```
HwndWrapper[FileName.exe;;ad445199-cf93-48a4-bd24-2f97d54c8af8]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because what you want basically doesn't exists, and the concept of `MainWindowHandle` is a gross misnomer that sneaked into the .Net Framework for everlasting confusion. From [There can be more than one (or zero): Converting a process to a window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/20/7806911.aspx):

> "I have a thread ID. How do I get the
>   corresponding window?"
>
> You can use the EnumThreadWindows
>   function to get all the windows on the
>   thread.
>
> "Yes, I know about EnumThreadWindows,
>   but how do I get the window that I
>   want?"
>
> Well, you haven't said what you wanted
>   yet.
>
> "I want the window that corresponds to
>   the thread."
>
> But which one? How will you decide
>   among all the windows?
>
> "That's what I'm asking you!"
>
> But you haven't yet described what you
>   want.
>
> "I want the window corresponding to
>   the thread. Why won't you answer my
>   question?"
>
> Note that saying, "I am looking for
>   the top-level unowned window" is a
>   step forward, but it still doesn't
>   uniquely identify a window. There can
>   be multiple top-level unowned windows
>   in a process. For example, Explorer
>   typically has lots of top-level
>   unowned windows. There's the desktop,
>   the taskbar, your open folder windows,
>   and property sheets. If you ask for
>   "the" top-level unowned window of
>   Explorer, which one do you want?
>
> Perhaps people are getting the idea
>   that there is a way to uniquely
>   specify "the" window for a process
>   because the System.Diagnostics.Process
>   object has a property called
>   MainWindowHandle. The documentation
>   for that property doesn't do anything
>   to dispel the notion, either. I have
>   no idea how that property decides
>   among multiple top-level unowned
>   windows.

The topic is also elaborated in MSDN Q&A [Get the Main Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301495.aspx):

> **Q** How can I find the main window for a process? I'm writing a Spy-like tool and I need to get the  main window (HWND) for a process so I can send it a message like WM_ACTIVATEAPP.
>
> **A** Which main window do you mean?